# Customise windows 11 context menu

Tags: window, right-click, custom-contextmenu

I want to add an option in windows 11 context menu but not in show more option submenu , it should added to the main context menu . I don't want to use the classic windows 10 context menu.

I tried with adding registry key

reg add “HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32” /f /ve

but its getting added to ShowMoreOption submenu.

I want to add to main context menu not in ShowMoreOption submenu.

looking forward for help.

Thanks

tried with registry key

reg add “HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32” /f /ve

but its getting added to ShowMoreOption submenu.

I want to add to main context menu not in ShowMoreOption submenu.

Comment: I would like to find that out too. Any programmatic access in any language possibly in admin mode would be fine.